# Difference between ADB drivers and MTK drivers?

Tags: rom-flashing, stock-android, rom, stock-rom

Flashing a ROM in an android through PC requires  drivers along with softwares in order to make the process success ,in case of drivers which drivers are needed and when ,what is relation between ADB drivers and MTK drivers are they same and if not how are they different .I appreciate the answer in detail

Answer (score -1):

Firstly it's not ABD driver it's Adb driver.Adb means Android Debug Bridge.ADB is a command-line utility included with Google's Android SDK. ADB can control your device over USB from a computer, copy files back and forth, install and uninstall apps, run shell commands, and more.When your device is in Fastboot/Download mode you can access your phone only through Adb.
For example if something goes wrong while flashing a rom and your phone is softbricked.Only way to access a bricked phone is through Adb.Adb mainly not used for flashing rom, It's used for flashing recovery/bootloader.

Comment: Thanks,but what are MTK drivers ,are adb drivers and MTK drivers same and if not how are they different .which drivers are required when etc